# Cassandra: Cannot remove a node and it gives gossip ERROR

Tags: cassandra

I have one reachable node in my cluster and I tried replacing it, it wasn't successful. So, I left the node and ignored the data loss because of the replication factor 3.

Now, when I try to decommission or add a server, it's not working as expected.

I'm getting these INFO messages in all the nodes. I have tried to assassinate and remove as well. This node doesn't show up in the node tool status. But I guess is, it is somewhere persisted and Gossips are giving issues.

> INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2021-05-29 07:25:37,404 Gossiper.java:1029 - InetAddress /10.43.5.118 is now DOWN
>
> INFO  [GossipStage:1] 2021-05-29 07:25:37,405 StorageService.java:2324 - Removing tokens [] for /10.43.5.118

And also, while restarting the node, I get an ERROR from the gossip which is NullPointerException. It's not able to get the host id. I tried removing it with the old method mentioned in the stackoverflow. Using JXM.

```
ERROR [GossipStage:1] 2021-05-29 08:48:35,229 CassandraDaemon.java:226 - Exception in thread Thread[GossipStage:1,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.getHostId(Gossiper.java:866) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.handleStateNormal(StorageService.java:2096) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.onChange(StorageService.java:1822) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.onJoin(StorageService.java:2536) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.handleMajorStateChange(Gossiper.java:1070) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.applyStateLocally(Gossiper.java:1181) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.GossipDigestAck2VerbHandler.doVerb(GossipDigestAck2VerbHandler.java:49) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:64) ~[apache-cassandra-3.9.jar:3.9]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Can someone let me know how to remove this node completely?

Comment: Please add the Cassandra  version you are working on

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Please remove all the data from removed node and try to start stand alone. if it works then again you should clear the data on that node and join the cluster with configuration change.

Also, if you have less amount of data on other nodes then please run cleanup and repair once before adding new node.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't have access to the removed node. It became unreachable and the data are already gone.

Comment: So you can clean the data again and restart the node. Hope, you will able to access.